# Grails project after deploy to heroku JSESSIONID cookie attribute secure is not set

Tags: spring-boot, grails, groovy, jenkins-groovy, grails-plugin

**Hi everyone,**

i would like to set JSESSIONID cookie at attribute secure to true.

So, i have configured in application.yml for server->session->cookie->secure:true, and once i did run the application in localhost it could set secure to true, but once i deploy it to heroku server via jenkins for my production it could not set secure to true like this picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrbAK.png)

**My grails project dependencies as the following.**

grails version = 3.3.14,
Java 8,
Gradle WrapperVersion 3.5

**So, if you have any suggestion to set JSESSIONID cookie at attribute secure to true for heroku server please advise me.**

**Thank you very much.**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Noted with thanks, and i have improved my question description, hopefully it will be bester.